# Проблема с передачей параметров методом POST

Tags: post, php, http

При выборе региона из инфоблока, явно видно, что формируется ссылка с параметром `GLOBAL_CITY`="номер региона", но после загрузке страницы новая форма согласно переданного параметра не отображается. Постоянно отображается одна и та же форма. Написал скрипт для отлавливания переменной методом POST, но такое чувство, что переменная не передается. [Ссылка на форму](http://test.rbrbank.ru/clients/private/crediting/consumer/new_online_form/online_form_connect.php).

```
<?php
// Подключаем форму On-line заявки
if (!isset($_POST['GLOBAL_CITY'])) {
    echo "Нет такой переменной - <strong>GLOBAL_CITY</strong>";
} else {
    $ID_CITY = $_POST['GLOBAL_CITY'];
    echo "Переменная <strong>GLOBAL_CITY</strong> - существует и она равна: $ID_CITY";
}

if (isset($_POST['GLOBAL_CITY']) == 1525) {
    include 'online_form_ufa.php';
} else {
    include 'online_form.php';
}
?>
```

[image: снимок]

**Добавлено.**

Переписал запрос, убрал проверку. Такое чувство, что в переменной пусто...

```
if($_GET['GLOBAL_CITY'] == 1054)
{ 
      echo 'online_form.php'; 
      include 'online_form.php'; 
} elseif ($_GET['GLOBAL_CITY'] == 1525)
{ 
      echo 'online_form_ufa.php'; 
      include 'online_form_ufa.php'; 
}
```

Comment: Попробовал зайти по ссылке - форма не отображается.

Comment: Ну вот, вижу, что разобрались...

Comment: Всеееее народ всем спасибо! Не знаю правда как тут всем по плюсику поставить за помощь :)
в общем суть такая, что я не GLOBAL_CITY должен ловить, а ту хрень из массива которую вытинул из $_REQUEST
if($_REQUEST['REGIONALBANK_SM_CITY'] == 1054){
 echo "Ура все получилось!";}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (isset($_POST['GLOBAL_CITY']) == 1525)` - это что??? Результат работы `isset()` будет true/false и что? Вы пытаетесь сделать:

```
if ((true/false) == 1525) {}
```

Бред, не правда ли?

Comment: Ну почему же, я пытаюсь сравнить, если существует значит отобразить тото если нет значит тото, или что-то не так!?

Comment: Как вы определили результат работы скрипта ? о_О

Comment: if (isset($_POST['GLOBAL_CITY']) == 1525)
Если существует $_POST['GLOBAL_CITY'] == 1525 - TRUE делай тото, 
Если нет FALSE значит делай тото,
Где тут БРЕД?

Comment: isset($_POST['GLOBAL_CITY']) возвращает true или false, а не значение переменной... Нужно так: if (isset($_POST['GLOBAL_CITY'])&& ($_POST['GLOBAL_CITY']== 1525))

Comment: Понял, спасибо :) Но терь вроде как работает проверка на существование, а вот на значение...

Comment: Попробуйте убрать проверку на существование, убедитесь, что в переменной передается именно то значение, которое вам нужно...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй вместо $_POST['GLOBAL_CITY'] использовать $_REQUEST['GLOBAL_CITY']. Такое впечатление что GLOBAL_CITY передается по гету

Comment: PS Если критично, что надо отправить постом именно по ссылке, то тут хитрее надо поступить - через жабаскрипт (скрытой формой или аяксом)

Comment: Попробовал $_REQUEST и $_GET ничего не изменилось, такое чувство что переменная раньше съедается, или же она живет до конца сценария!?

Comment: Значение переданной переменной немогу отловить

Answer (score 0):

1. согласно вашим скринам переменная отдается методом GET для POST необходимо в теге form указывать method="post"
2. должно быть верно указан адрес файла обработчика формы в поле action, если action не указан запрос будет посылаться на текущую открытую страницу что как видно и происходит.
3. `if (isset($_POST['GLOBAL_CITY']) == 1525)` заменить на

   ```
   if (isset($_POST['GLOBAL_CITY']) && $_POST['GLOBAL_CITY'] == 1525)
   ```
4. чтобы посмотреть какие именно переменные приходят воспользуйтесь `print_r($_REQUEST);`

Comment: Вот что выдал мне print_r($_REQUEST);
Array ( [PHPSESSID] => c84c751e15907afd14faab2555c71ca5 [REGIONALBANK_SM_GUEST_ID] => 41068 [REGIONALBANK_SM_LAST_VISIT] => 02.04.2012 16:02:22 [REGIONALBANK_SM_CITY] => 1054 ), массив с данными,
скорее всего [REGIONALBANK_SM_CITY] => 1054, это то что мне надо, тока я вот понять не могу это что переменная  какая0то если да, то как к ней обратиться? значит я уже должен ловить не GLOBAL_CITY а что-то REGIONALBANK_SM_CITY!?